# Store value of variable to a file in columnwise which is iterating using python

Tags: python

My code is like this .

```
inputfile=np.genfromtxt('test1.dat')
for data in inputfile:
    lat=floor(data)+(floor(abs((data-floor(data))*100))/60)+....
    print lat
```

In command window I can see

```
12.9579738889
12.9579736111
12.9579727778
12.9579719444
12.9579711111
12.9579702778
12.9579694444
.......
```

But I want to save it in a text file in my working directory .
I am not getting how to proceed. All attempts failed.
Please give suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format the question properly !

Comment: Please show at least a few of *all attempts* and the problems/errors that occurred.

Comment: Just try open a new file using fopen and write the output.

Comment: Yeah new to python and not used this site so format is not proper .

Comment: inputfile=np.genfromtxt('test1.dat')
x=[]
#lat=[]
for data in inputfile:
    lat=floor(data)+(floor(abs((data-floor(data))*100))/60)+(floor(((abs((data-floor(data))*100))-int((abs((data-floor(data))*100))))*100)/3600)+(((((abs((data-floor(data))*100))-int((abs((data-floor(data))*100))))*100)-floor(int((((abs((data-floor(data))*100))-int((abs((data-floor(data))*100))))*100))))*1000)/3600000
    x.append(lat)
    print lat
    np.savetxt('output1.dat','w','lat')

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple. Use `open` to open the file (get a file object which encapsulates the file descriptor) and then simply write to that file. In a true Pythonic way you'll want to use a context manager (`with open(..) as file`), so the the file is closed automatically when out of context.

```
inputfile=np.genfromtxt('test1.dat')
with open("/path/to/output.file", "w") as f:
    for data in inputfile:
        lat=floor(data)+(floor(abs((data-floor(data))*100))/60)+....
        f.write("%f\n" % lat)
```

Comment: Hey! I got the output file. But why it is giving only 12 . digits after decimal is not printing ?

Comment: Thanks randomir.

Comment: @SatinathDebnath He meant %f

Comment: Yes, it should have been ``%f``. It's fixed.

Comment: Oh nice. I got what I wanted. Thanks all of you once again . It seems I  need to give  more time on basics.

Answer (score -1):

You can do following. I used f-string to format output, which is available in Python >= 3.6, but you can you any version to do some calculation first and then output the value.

```
>>> with open('test1.dat') as f_in:
...     with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as f_out:
...         for data in f_in:
...             f_out.write(f"{floor(data)+(floor(abs((data-floor(data))*100))/60)}\n")
```

if your data has more than one values you can use split function:

```
lan, lot = (float(x) for x in data.split(' '))
```

where ' ' is your separator between those values

Comment: Cool new feature. Although isn't  `data` supposed to be `line` in your example?

Comment: On the same note I want to ask one more question . Actually I have two columns of data latitude and longitude in dms.milliseconds format . I am converting it in degree through above equation separately . Is it possible to iterate both lat and lon columns from same file  and do manipulation and again save to previous file. I am plotting them  in google map

Comment: You probably should use ``float(line)`` instead of ``data`` (see [numpy.genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) docs)

Comment: @kabanus, yes, it should be data. I change my code.

Comment: Dear Vlad Bezden Sir, Is it possible to iterate both lat and lon columns from same file  in two variabls using previous equation  and save them in another file. Now I am doing it two times for latitude and longitude

Comment: @SatinathDebnath, yes, I added more information to the example above.

Comment: Sir, I am using dat file without any comma between two data . Only white space is present between columns.

Comment: @SatinathDebnath then use data.split(' ') (space) instead of ';'

Comment: for value in inputfile:
   lan, data = value.split('')
   latitude=floor(data)+...
   f.write("%.8f\n" % latitude)
   #error:numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @SatinathDebnath use lan, lat = data.split(' ')

Comment: @VladBezden, your code is still incorrect - it produces ``TypeError: a float is required``, since the ``data`` variable contains a string, and the ``floor`` function requires ``float``. See my previous comment.

Comment: @randomir I updated code to convert it to float.

Comment: @VladBezden ,I have modified code as you suggested , But this time it is throws numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split' error.   Is it because I am loading file though np.genfromtxt() command?

Comment: for mata in inputfile:  lan, data = (float(x) for x in mata.split(' '))   latitude=floor(data)+(floor(abs((data-floor(data))*100) +...    f.write("%.8f\n" % latitude)

Comment: @VladBezden Sir, Would u please post your final code once again in steps. I am not getting using split function. Somewhere I am doing mistakes